# Python import: attempted relative import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I had some errors on import from top level folderin Python
(version Python 3.6.9)
My folder structure is below:

```
-topfolder 
    alltestfunc.py
    -subfolder
        update_test.py
```

I am trying to import alltestfunc.py in update_test.py , that's all.

The errors which i had:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alltestfunc'
```

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

etc..

Thanx a lot

Comment: Thanx for the link but it didn't work for me and I still don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the code like this?

```
python topfolder/subfolder/update_test.py
```

This would make the `update_test.py` the `__main__` file, or the starting point of your program. From there on out you cannot do an import one level up, only from subdirectories.

If you have some script on the `topfolder` level that is called and then executes the `update_test.py` you should be good.